# what are the use of parentheses in this Lua pattern?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

base string is: `IP: 192.168.0.1`

Passing that string to string.gmatch function(besides below patterns) will return the following results:

pattern: `IP: (%d+.%d+.%d+.%d+)`
-->192.168.0.1

pattern: `IP: %d+.%d+.%d+.%d+`
-->IP: 192.168.0.1

My question is that what are the meaning of those parentheses to the Lua pattern matching engine?
Why by using the parentheses in the first pattern, the `IP:` string omitted but in the second pattern no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything inside parentheses is a [capture group](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html/#5.4.1); any part of the input string matched by the part of the pattern in parentheses is captured and returned by `match()` and `gmatch()`.  If there are no capture groups in the pattern, the entire string is returned.

```
local x, y, z = ("123456"):match("(%d)%d(%d)%d(%d)%d")
print(x, y, z)
-- 1, 3, 5
```

At any point after the associated capture group is specified, `%1`, `%2` etc. may be used to access the captured value:

```
local x, y = ("123123123"):match("(%d%d%d)%1(%1)")
print(x, y)
-- 123, 123
```

This is most often seen in the third parameter of `string.gsub()`, but may be used in any of the pattern matching functions.

Answer (score -1):

In this case it should just be used for grouping things, which doesn't matter much either way here.