# when using pattern matching in Lua with parenthesis, how does one use "%2" to get the capture group

Tags: json, lua, openwrt, lua-patterns

I am trying to parse a text file and converting it to a table (or JSON) using lua. Example test file is as follows:

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 3598 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.117 dst=137.194.2.78 sport=59078 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=298 src=137.194.2.78 dst=132.227.127.212 sport=80 dport=59078 packets=3 bytes=567 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 udp      17 55 src=192.168.1.117 dst=157.56.149.60 sport=49991 dport=3544 packets=5 bytes=445 [UNREPLIED] src=157.56.149.60 dst=132.227.127.212 sport=3544 dport=49991 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 3420 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.104 dst=193.51.224.187 sport=35918 dport=443 packets=19 bytes=2521 src=193.51.224.187 dst=132.227.127.212 sport=443 dport=35918 packets=16 bytes=9895 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 udp      17 59 src=192.168.1.117 dst=192.168.1.255 sport=17500 dport=17500 packets=139 bytes=23908 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.1.255 dst=192.168.1.117 sport=17500 dport=17500 packets=0 bytes=0 mark=0 use=2
...
```

Notice that the data in each line can be split into two parts based on the direction (forward and reverse path flows).
In case you have a linux system/openwrt router, you may get a similar test file using the `conntrack` command, or by reading `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`.

What I wish to retrieve is the following information:

```
{ 1:
    {
    "bytes":    298,
    "src":      "192.168.1.117",
    "sport":    59078,
    "layer4":   "tcp",
    "dst":      "137.194.2.78",
    "dport":    80,
    "layer3":   "ipv4",
    "packets":  4,
    "rbytes":   567,
    "rpackets": 3
    },
{ 2: ...
```

where rbytes, rpackets are for the bytes and packets in the reverse direction (second half of line 1 in my example text file).

My parser is as follows:*

```
function conntrack(callback)
local connt = {}
if io.open("conntrack.temp", "r") then

    for line in io.lines("conntrack.temp") do
            line = line:match("^(.-( [^ =]+=).-)%2")
        local entry, flags = _parse_mixed_record(line, " +")

            if flags[6] ~= "TIME_WAIT" then
                entry.layer3 = flags[1]
                entry.layer4 = flags[3]
                for i=1, #entry do
                    entry[i] = nil
                end
                if callback then
                    callback(entry)
                else
                    connt[#connt+1] = entry
                end
            end
    end   
else
    return nil
end
return connt
end

function _parse_mixed_record(cnt, delimiter)
delimiter = delimiter or "  "
local data = {}
local flags = {}

for i, l in pairs(cnt:split("\n")) do
    for j, f in pairs(l:split(delimiter)) do
        local k, x, v = f:match('([^%s][^:=]*) *([:=]*) *"*([^\n"]*)"*')
        if k then
            if x == "" then
                table.insert(flags, k)
            else
                data[k] = v
            end
        end
    end
end

return data, flags
end
```

Calling the above function (after including a simple `split` method in the code), I can parse the file **only upto the first half of each line**. So basically, no `rbytes` or `rpackets` are parsed. I know the code responsible for this is

> line = line:match("^(.-( [^ =]+=).-)%2")

A `print(line)` statement following this line in code shows me:

> ipv4     2 tcp      6 3598 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.117 dst=137.194.2.78 sport=59078 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=298

So, the statement splits each line of the file using a confusing pattern matching which I kind of understand after playing around with it a bit. The part I still don't get is the `%2` which occurs after capturing the pattern. I know it is used to somehow access the pattern caught, but how should I change this statement so that `line` contains both the forward path bytes and packet count, as well as the reverse path?
My main question is: **what exactly is the pattern in this statement?** I'm probably going to remove this line to parse the whole statement, but I wanted to understand why the original coders are doing this.

I've been through the lua pattern matching manual but I'm still confused on capturing output with `%<some_number>`. Why doesn't `%1` or `%3` work?

Two relevant stackoverflow questions I found: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693730/what-are-the-use-of-parentheses-in-this-lua-pattern), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226150/use-string-gsub-to-replace-strings-but-only-whole-words). A deeper explanation would be appreciated.

Also, currently I can't recover the timeout value (5th word in line1 `3598`) or the connection state (`ESTABLISHED`, `[ASSURED]`) with the code I have provided here. I'm still a beginner at lua and hope to crack this soon.

*NOTE: This parser is my fixed version of the one available in the luci sys module on openwrt routers. See [original luci.sys sourcecode](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/browser/luci/trunk/libs/sys/luasrc/sys.lua) for details.

While working with on attitude adjustment 12.09, I noticed that their net.conntrack() isn't working due to a failure in parsing the object to a proper JSON format. The relevant function using this pattern is given in the sys.lua file, called function conntrack(callback) and internal function _parse_mixed_record(cnt, delimiter). My router used luci-0.11 and lua 5.1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pattern was designed to keep only the forward part of each line. Here's how it does that. The second parenthesis, `( [^ =]+=)`, captures the first substring of the form `" stuff="`. Then the `%2` at the end of the pattern will only match if that same, string, `" stuff="` appears again. So on a line like

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 3598 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.117 dst=137.194.2.78 sport=59078 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=298 src=137.194.2.78 dst=132.227.127.212 sport=80 dport=59078 packets=3 bytes=567 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2
```

the second capture will be `" src="`, so the first capture, which is what is assigned to `line`, will be the whole initial portion of the line until just before the *second* time `src=` appears, that is, this initial part:

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 3598 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.117 dst=137.194.2.78 sport=59078 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=298
```

If you wanted to get the second half too, and assign it to a different variable, you could replace the `line = ...` statement with

```
line1, _, line2 = line:match("^(.-( [^ =]+=).-)(%2.*)$")
```

This would assign to line1 the first half of the line (as was previosly assigned to line), and to line2, the remainder, sarting from the second occurence of `" src="`. For the example line above, you'd get

```
line1 = "ipv4     2 tcp      6 3598 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.1.117 dst=137.194.2.78 sport=59078 dport=80 packets=4 bytes=298"
line2 = " src=137.194.2.78 dst=132.227.127.212 sport=80 dport=59078 packets=3 bytes=567 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=2"
```

Note: The `_` in between `line1` and `line2` is there to catch the second capture (which here is the string `" src="`), remember that match returns all captures, in order, whether you want them or not.